# How do I hide a div class when an input id value is empty?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, html, hide

I've been stuck on this for days now, so I'd be really grateful if someone could help me solve this issue.

I'm doing a Wordpress theme and I have an options panel where the user can enter their Twitter username. I want the Twitter icon to appear in the footer if they enter a username, and I want the Twitter icon to disappear if they leave the field empty and don't enter a username.

The Twitter icon image is called in a div class called '.twitter' and currently, the Twitter icon is always there, even if the input id value is empty. So what I want to do is hide this div class when the input id value is empty so that the icon disappears.

When I asked this question before someone said to use this jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    if($('#mytheme_twitter').val() == '' ){$('.twitter').hide();}  

    $('#mytheme_twitter').on('change' , function() {

         if( this.value != ''){

               $('.twitter').show(); 
          }
          else{
               $('.twitter').hide(); 
         }
    });
  });
</script>
```

I put this jQuery in my header.php but for some reason it's not working. The name of the div class is definitely '.twitter' so could it be the selector of the input id that is wrong? I went into the options panel on Firefox and highlighted the input box with Firebug and it is definitely '#mytheme_twitter' I've also tried 'input#mytheme_twitter' but that doesn't work either.

The options panel is in another php file, not the index.php one. Could that be the reason why it's not working... because that input id hasn't been defined in the index.php? I don't know much about this myself because I'm a jQuery noob and I've only recently started getting the hang of php too.

Comment: You would be better off to do this in PHP.  if ($twitter_account) { // Show your div }

Comment: Waitwaitwait, are the `#mytheme_twitter` and `.twitter` boxes on completely different pages?

Comment: This ***should*** be done in php.

Comment: Yes, they are on different pages. I take it this is the problem? What php would I need to use then?

Comment: Well, this is a classic case of "what did you expect to happen?". Javascript operates on the current page. How would it know about inputs on other pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your JS is calling to a box that is in the admin. It can't pull that value unless it and the `.twitter` are on the same page (Without some overkill functionality).

You'd be better off doing this in PHP: something like this

```
if(get_option('twitter', 'your-page')) !=='') { //show div }
```

That would be placed in your footer.php

Comment: So as your question states - yes, it's wrong because they don't coexist in the same DOM.

Comment: Did you use my code above? or did you use `if(get_option('your_option_name')) !==''){ }` where `your_option_name` is the OPTION name you made when you created the page?

Comment: I've tried both if(get_option('twitter', 'your-page')) and if(get_option('your_option_name')) but both give parse errors. What is meant to replace 'your-page'?

Comment: I've sorted it! It's a slightly modified version of your code but thanks for giving me the basis! ^_^

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript is working fine: http://jsfiddle.net/XdeHP/

Your problem must lie elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$("#mytheme_twitter").change(function(){
if( $(this).val() != ''){

        $('.twitter').show(); 
    }else{
        $('.twitter').hide(); 
    }
});
```